# How to read from sqlite database with dash?

Tags: dash-shell

In bash, I use this to read from a sqlite database:

```
TMP=`echo "select * from Table limit 1;" | sqlite3 mysqlite3database.db`
tokens=(${TMP//|/ })
PARAM_1=${tokens[0]}
PARAM_2=${tokens[1]}
PARAM_3=${tokens[2]}
PARAM_4=${tokens[3]}
```

This unfortunately does not work with dash - is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

```
PARAM_1=${tokens% *}
tokens=${tokens#* }
PARAM_2=${tokens% *}
```

and so forth